# how to save multiple objects to the database in django rest framework views

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework, django-views, many-to-many

so what i'm trying to do is add a new product to my data base using django's restapi
but a product may contain multiple categories which are related throught a third many to many
model and extra pictures which are ForeignKeyed to the product

this is my models.py

```
class Products(models.Model):
    product_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=35, null=False, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0.)
    main_image = models.FileField(upload_to='shop/images')
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, default=datetime.now)

class Category(models.Model):
    category_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, default=datetime.now)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Category'

class ProductsCategory(models.Model):
    productscategory_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(to=Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(to=Products, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, default=datetime.now)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'ProductsCategory'

class Pictures(models.Model):
    picture_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to='shop/images')
    product = models.ForeignKey(to=Products, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, default=datetime.now)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Pictures'
```

and heres what i've tryed:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([IsModerator])
def create_product(request):
    product_details = ProductsSerializer(request.POST, request.FILES)
    pictures = PicturesSerializer(request.POST, request.FILES, many=True)
    category_list = request.POST.getlist("category")

            if product_details.is_valid() and validate_file_extension(request.FILES.get("main_image")):
            try:
                product = product_details.save()
                if len(category_list) > 0:
                    for i in category_list:
                        category = Category.objects.get(category=i)
                        ProductsCategory.objects.create(category=category, product=product)
                if pictures:
                    for image in request.FILES.getlist("image"):
                        if validate_file_extension(image):
                            Pictures.objects.create(image=image, product=product)
                        else:
                            error = {"error": "invalid extra pictures extension"}
                            return Response(error)
                return Response((product_details.data, pictures.data, category_list), status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
            except Exception as e:
                return Response(e)
        else:
            return Response((product_details._errors, pictures._errors), status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

and the output:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i54vl.png)

how am i supposed to use this content input?
or if you know a better for my main question of saving multiple models in the database and their relationships please leave an answer, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you change your `models.py` structure to this:

```py
from django.db import models

class Category(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural  =  "Categories"

class Picture(models.Model):
    image = models.FileField(upload_to='shop/images')
    product = models.ForeignKey(to=Products, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, default=datetime.now)
    
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=35, null=False, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0.)
    main_image = models.FileField(upload_to='shop/images')
    more_images = models.ManyToManyField(Pictures, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Then in your `serializer.py` add:

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Category, Picture, Product

class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = "__all__"

class PictureSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Picture
        fields = "__all__"

class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = "__all__"
```

In your `views`, I suggest you use `ViewSets`:
`views.py`

```py
from .models import Category, Picture, Product
from .serializer import CategorySerializer, PictureSerializer, ProductSerializer
from rest_framework import viewsets
# import custom permissions if any

class CategoryViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    
    serializer_class = CategorySerializer
    queryset = Category.objects.all()

class PictureViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    
    serializer_class = PictureSerializer
    queryset = Picture.objects.all()

class ProductViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [IsModerator]
```

In your app's `urls.py`, add the router for your viewsets and it will create the paths for your views automatically:

```py
from django.urls import path
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'category', views.CategoryViewSet, basename='category')
router.register(r'picture', views.PictureViewSet, basename='picture')
router.register(r'product', views.ProductViewSet, basename='product')

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Changes log:

- You do not need to add an ID field to every model, Django does that for you. Unless it's a particular case.
- Your database tables are named after your model by default. So no need to specify that too.
- I simplified your models' structure to make it cleaner. But it still does what you want it to do.
- Django adds an `s` to create a plural name for every model. So you can name it in singular form unless needed to specify. eg. `categories`.
- The viewsets will reduce your work by providing you with listing and retrieval actions.

To access a specific instance of eg. a product, you will just add a `/<product id>` after the product listing and creation endpoint.

> Note: You have to add the id without the brackets.

I also suggest you go through this [DRF tutorial](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/). It will improve your understanding of  Django REST framework.